# duplicate symbol _XBAnimationInterpolatorEaseInOut

Tags: ios, github, duplicate-symbol

I've created a single view iOS app. Added pod 'XBPageCurl'. When I add #import "XBPageCurlView.h" to any view controller I get this error

```
duplicate symbol _XBAnimationInterpolatorEaseInOut in:
/Users/alexander/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CurlTest-fphbvwtzauotgidxuqzdympohxqz/Build/Intermediates/CurlTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/CurlTest.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ViewController.o
/Users/alexander/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CurlTest-fphbvwtzauotgidxuqzdympohxqz/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPods-XBPageCurl.a(XBAnimation.o)
ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
```

This is not happening with a test project from [github](https://github.com/marcpalmer/XBPageCurl).

Any idea how to get rid of it?

Comment: Something you're importing has a definition for `XBAnimationInterpolatorEaseInOut` rather than just a declaration.  What do references to that symbol look like?

Comment: It's a block. From [here](https://github.com/marcpalmer/XBPageCurl/blob/master/XBPageCurl/XBAnimation.m)

Answer (score 1):

In build settings set "No Common Blocks" to NO

Answer (score 0):

I removed any reference of interpolator block and moved the logic from it to `- (BOOL)step:(NSTimeInterval)dt`